# c# Linq compare file with same file name without extension

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i had trying to compare 2 folder to check whether there are same file name exist in both folder or not.
Is there any simple way to direct search it without comparing the file name only without the extension?

As Folder A's files are .MAP and Folder B's files are .IJM (I just wanted to compare the file name only)
Because it may exist ABC.MAP and ABC.IJM in both the folder.

So far the code I tried was as below:

```
// Create two identical or different temporary folders   
// on a local drive and change these file paths.  
string pathA = @"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\POOLING PATH";
string pathB = @"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROCESS PATH";

System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathB);

// Take a snapshot of the file system.  
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var test in list1)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(test.FullName) + "\n");
}
foreach (var test in list2)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(test.FullName) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Your directions are unclear, so what do you want, 2 lots of results, those that share file names, and those that dont? be specific, does it matter which directory they come out of. do you want the results that include the full path, ect, ect, ect, ect

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes, i need the path as well.

Sorry for the lousy english, what i wanted is to check both folder that have the same file name, then input the full path to a list

Comment: So its just like a duplicate check?

Comment: You can try *Linq* e.g.

`var result = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(pathA, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Select(A => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(A))
  .Intersect(Directory
     .EnumerateFiles(pathB, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Select(B => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(B)))
  .OrderBy(name => name);` then

`richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko can u try to post on as answer?

Comment: @MichaelRandall i was just try to check both folder and to get duplicate filename exist on both folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try a *Linq* query, e.g.

```
 // *.map, *.ijm: 
 // ...As Folder A's files are .MAP and Folder B's files are .IJM
 var result = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(pathA, "*.map", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
   .Select(A => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(A)) 
   .Intersect(Directory 
      .EnumerateFiles(pathB, "*.ijm", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
      .Select(B => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(B)),
       StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
   .OrderBy(name => name);
```

followed by

```
  richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Edit:** if you want to *play* with *set*s (see comments below), let's collect files into `HashSet<string>`s:

```
  HashSet<string> filesA = new HashSet<string>(Directory
      .EnumerateFiles(pathA, "*.map", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
      .Select(A => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(A)),
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  HashSet<string> filesB = new HashSet<string>(Directory
      .EnumerateFiles(pathB, "*.ijm", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
      .Select(B => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(B)),
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Now, you can put:

```
  // filesA has only files that are in filesB as well
  // filesA.IntersectWith(filesB);

  // filesA has only files that are NOT in filesB
  // filesA.ExceptWith(filesB);

  // filesB has only files that are NOT in filesA
  // filesB.ExceptWith(filesA);

  // filesA has only files that are either in filesA or in filesB (not in both)
  //filesA.SymmetricExceptWith(filesB)
```

Comment: if i wanted to search by some specific format of the file name, is that i change the *.* to ABC.* ?

Comment: @Marcus Tan: yes, if you are looking for a special mask, put `*ABC*.*`, if format can't be represented as mask, use `Where(file => /*condition here*/)` for it

Comment: meaning that if i wanted to search the file name start with ABC, then i type *ABC.* ?

Comment: @Marcus Tan: if file name should *start* from `ABC` the mask should be `ABC*.*` or `"ABC*.map"` (`"ABC*.ijm"`), i.e. `ABC` then zero or more any characters followed by `.map` extension

Comment: is that possible if also can filter out that is not exist in both folder?

Comment: @Marcus Tan: Put `Except` instead of `Intersect` to find out all files that are in `pathA`, but not in `pathB`

Comment: I try change the Intersect to except but not working

Answer (score 1):

Note this code is untested, but sounds like you're looking for an intersect?

So maybe something like this...

```
var pathA = @"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\POOLING PATH";
var pathB = @"C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PROCESS PATH";

List<string> GetFiles(string path) => Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name)).ToList();

var filesA = GetFiles(pathA);
var filesB = GetFiles(pathB);

// should be a list of file names found in both lists
var common = filesA.Intersect(filesB).ToList();
```